# Getting Facebook FQL response into a data container

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to add FQL queries to Sociogram examle:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/02/sociogram-a-sample-application-exploring-the-facebook-sdk-and-the-graph-api/

**I am receiving data but am getting the error: "ReferenceError: data is not defined"**

It works with a Graph API call:

```
try {           
            FB.api("/" + id + "/events?limit=20", function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    self.showErrorPage();
                } else {
                    $('#content').append(new fb.views.Events({model: new Backbone.Model(response)}).el);
                }
            });
    },
```

But not with a FQL call:

```
try {
    FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT name, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())'
   }, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    self.showErrorPage();
                } else {
                    $('#content').append(new fb.views.Events({model: new Backbone.Model(response)}).el);
                }
            });
    },
```

**The Graph API call (that works) results in a data []** and the FQL one looks like it is full of Objects without being in the data [] container.  I'm pretty sure this is the difference but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: This is not so. You'll get the response in the same format. [Graph API Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fevents%3Flimit%3D20%26fields%3Dname%2Cid)

[FQL Query Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name%2C%20eid%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20IN%20(SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me())

Please check the response of FQL with- `console.log(response)`

Comment: I've checked and it's definitely not the same - ReferenceError: data is not defined.  From the Console.log I can see lot's of objects, all on their own.

Graph API query in the console
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7ge1cqyEHgydk1qcjlqR3RqY2s/edit?usp=sharing

FQL in the Console: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7ge1cqyEHgyU041dllSQk5QYzg/edit?usp=sharing